# Geometry , gre problem

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

Smallest distance from a point P to any point on the circle C is 5 and the largest distance  from the the point P to the circle is C is 11 . If point P is situated outside the circle C , then what is the distance between centre of the circle and the point P ?
MY View about problem ---------
11 is tangent to the circle C from point P

lets assume k is the point where tangent touch the circle C,

p is point outside circle 
X radius 
K touch point to tangent 
O centre of the circle 
so that ko is perpendicular to Kp 
by right angle triangle law po2= ko2+kp2
po=5+X
Ko=X
Kp=11
But answer is not matching with actual answer

Comment: The point on the circle furthers from $P$ is not a point of tangency with the line from $P$; instead, it is the point on the *opposite* side of the circle from $P$. From this, you can determine the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the point $P$ is located outside of the circle, then we should draw a line, passing from $P$, and the center of the circle, $C$, whicih we call that line $l$. It is intuitive that $l$ intersects the circle in two points, $M$ and $N$ respectively. Then there are two segments: $\overline {PM}$ and $\overline {PN}$. According to the problem we have:

$|\overline {PM}|=5$ and $|\overline {PN}|=11$

So the diameter of the circle is equal to the difference of these values ( $\overline{MN}$ is one of the diameters of the circle), and hence:

$2R=11-5=6 \rightarrow R=3$

So the distance, between the center of the circle and $P$ is equal to:

$|\overline {CP}|=|\overline {PM}|+R=5+3=8$,
in which $C$ is the center of the circle.

You can see it in the following picture:
[image]

Note that the tangent to the circle is not the longest distance from the point $P$, to the points of the circle, since if we draw the tangent and it intersects the circle in $S$, then we have the triangle $PSN$ which is  $90$ degrees at the angle $S$, and we know the longest segment in a rectangular triangle is its hypotenuse, not the legs

Answer (score 1):

The line through $P$ and the center $O$ of the circle hits the circle at the two points of minimal and maximal distance. That means the two points are diametrically opposite on the circle, so the diameter is $11 - 5=6$ and so the radius is $3$.

Hence the distance from $P$ to $O$ is $5 + 3 = 8$, right?